# Separating elements in a string by white space into two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am trying to store the following strings in a file into a two dimensional array. What code I have written works except for when an element contains a space, it separates into an additional element. Here is my file:

```
Student1    New York   
Student 2   Miami
Student3    Chicago
```

So I would want my output to look like this:

```
[Student1] [New York]
[Student 2] [Miami]
[Student3] [Chicago]
```

This is my actual output:

```
[Student1] [New] [York]
[Student] [2] [Miami]
[Student3] [Chicago]
```

Here is what I've written so far:

```
        String file= "file.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((file = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                String strSingleSpace = file.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "); 
                String[] obj = strSingleSpace.trim().split("\\s+");
                int i=0;
                String[][] newString = new String[obj.length][]; 

                for(String temp : obj){
                    newString[i++]=temp.trim().split("\\s+");
                }

                List<String[]> yourList = Arrays.asList(newString);
                System.out.println(yourList.get(0)[0] + " " + yourList.get(1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just giving you some "food for thought": your code is treating all lines **the same way**. As if they were looking exactly the same. Although you already made it very clear, that some lines have a **different** format.

In other words: there is no point in **blindly** splitting on spaces, if sometimes spaces **belong** into the first **or** the second column.

Instead:

1. Determine the last *index* of a number in a line - and then everything up to that index "makes up the first column".
2. The remainder of that line (after that last number) should go into the second column; only call trim() on that remaining string to get rid of the potentially **leading** spaces.

You could put all of that into a single matching regular expression too; but as that is probably some kind of homework; I leave that exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your specific test case it will work if you change this line:

```
String[] obj = strSingleSpace.trim().split("\\s+");\
```

to this:

```
String[] obj = strSingleSpace.trim().split("\\s+", 1);
```